# Preguntas que están correctamente hechas pero no agregan el código ni el error que tienen

Tags: discusión

He visto varias preguntas que son correctas en su forma de preguntar, pero que no agregan su código o el error que les da su IDE, etc.

¿Qué podría hacer con esas preguntas?

¿Votarlas negativamente, o qué cosa?

Ejemplo: [Este es un ejemplo que vi, le comente al usuario que agregara su código](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/79669/a%C3%B1adir-un-n%C3%BAmero-concreto-de-edittext-determinado-por-el-usuario-de-la-aplicaci?noredirect=1#comment146648_79669) (En la pregunta ya se agrego el código pero fue una de las que vi sin agregar el  código).

Comment: La pregunta no es clara. Si están hechas correctamente entonces no necesita ni código ni error por otro lado, si necesitan código o el error, entonces no están hechas correctamente. Ayudaría que pusieras ejemplos específicos. Por cierto, aquí con 15 puntos de reputación se gana [el primer privilegio de moderación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) :)

Comment: lo que quiero comentar es que no agregan su codigo para poder ver mas con atencion su error y poder ayudarlos mas rapidos he visto preguntas bien hechas pero que no agregan el codigo para poder ayudarlos mejor.

Comment: Agrega enlaces a preguntas así como ejemplos para entender mejor a qué te refieres

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El ejemplo que has incluido es muy reciente, publicada apenas hace una hora. En la [revisión 1](https://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/79669/1) puede verse la publicación sin código.

No me parece que sea una buena pregunta porque no incluye lo buscado/investigado para hacer lo que esté preguntando.

El indicarle que agregue el código no me me parece del todo necesario, pero tampoco está del todo mal, lo mejor hubiese sido que agregue lo que ha buscado/investigado.

En relación a votar negativamente, yo prefiero no votar así en preguntas del día en curso de usuarios nuevos (reputación menor de 100) y en las no han recibido ningún comentario. Si la pregunta ya tiene más de un día y comentarios también con mas de un día, incluyendo los míos, el OP no ha dado muestras de intentar mejorar su pregunta y no veo forma de ayudarle a mejorar su pregunta editándola, entonces es cuando voto negativamente.